Problem combining two Pinescript indicators - volume profile and liquidation levels
I'm attempting to combine a volume profile indicator and liquidation levels indicator. By themselves they both work fine however, when combined they compile without errors and will start fine but after each new candle the liquidation level lines start disappearing. After the third candle is posted, the script stops with this error:

Study Error, Error on bar 6613: In 'array.get()' function. Index 0 is out of bounds, array size is 0., at #main():293

I have checked that variable names are unique between the two scripts but it does appear that something in one script is affecting the other. Also, if it helps, the "line.new" function appears once in both scripts and I found if I comment out this line in the volume profile script, the liquidation levels script functions properly but, of course, the volume profile doesn't display.
Following is the script(s):
//***** Liquidation Levels *****
//@version = 5
indicator(title = "Volume Profile & Liquidation Lines", shorttitle = "Vol + Liq", overlay = true,
 max_lines_count = 500, max_boxes_count = 120, max_labels_count = 50, max_bars_back = 1000, linktoseries = true, precision = 4)
 
//***********************************************Volume Profile****************

vp_lookback   = input.int(defval = 384, title = "Volume Lookback Depth [10-1000]", minval = 10, maxval = 1000)
vp_max_bars   = input.int(defval = 200, title = "Number of Bars [10-500]", minval = 10, maxval = 500)
vp_bar_mult   = input.int(defval = 25, title = "Bar Length Multiplier [10-100]", minval = 10, maxval = 100)
vp_bar_offset = input.int(defval = 9, title = "Bar Horizontal Offset [0-100]", minval = 1, maxval = 100)
vp_bar_width  = input.int(defval = 2, title = "Bar Width [1-20]", minval = 1, maxval = 20)
vp_delta_type = input.string(defval = "Both", title = "Delta Type", options = ['Both', 'Bullish', 'Bearish'])
vp_poc_show   = input.bool(defval = true, title = "Show POC Line")
vp_bar_color  = input.color(defval = color.rgb(80, 115, 148, 60), title = "Bar Color")
vp_poc_color  = input.color(defval = color.rgb(121, 105, 192, 10), title = "POC Color")

/////Variables
float vp_Vmax = 0.0
int vp_VmaxId = 0
int vp_N_BARS = vp_max_bars
var int vp_first = time
vp_a_P = array.new_float((vp_N_BARS + 1), 0.0)
vp_a_V = array.new_float(vp_N_BARS, 0.0)
vp_a_D = array.new_float(vp_N_BARS, 0.0)
vp_a_W = array.new_int(vp_N_BARS, 0)

/////Calculations
float vp_HH = ta.highest(high, vp_lookback)
float vp_LL = ta.lowest(low, vp_lookback)

if barstate.islast
    float vp_HL = (vp_HH - vp_LL) / vp_N_BARS
    for jv = 1 to (vp_N_BARS + 1)
        array.set(vp_a_P, (jv-1), (vp_LL + vp_HL * jv))
    for iv = 0 to (vp_lookback - 1)
        int Dc = 0
        array.fill(vp_a_D, 0.0)
        for jv = 0 to (vp_N_BARS - 1)
            float Pj = array.get(vp_a_P, jv)
            if low[iv] < Pj and high[iv] > Pj and (vp_delta_type == "Bullish" ? 
             close[iv] >= open[iv] : (vp_delta_type == "Bearish" ? close[iv] <= open[iv] : true))
                float Dj = array.get(vp_a_D, jv)
                float dDj = Dj + nz(volume[iv])
                array.set(vp_a_D, jv, dDj)
                Dc := Dc + 1
        for jv = 0 to (vp_N_BARS - 1)
            float Vj = array.get(vp_a_V, jv)
            float Dj = array.get(vp_a_D, jv)
            float dVj = Vj + ((Dc > 0) ? (Dj / Dc) : 0.0)
            array.set(vp_a_V, jv, dVj)
    vp_Vmax := array.max(vp_a_V)
    vp_VmaxId := array.indexof(vp_a_V, vp_Vmax)
    for jv = 0 to (vp_N_BARS - 1)
        float Vj = array.get(vp_a_V, jv)
        int Aj = math.round(vp_bar_mult * Vj / vp_Vmax)
        array.set(vp_a_W, jv, Aj)

/////Plotting
if barstate.isfirst
    vp_first := time
vp_change = ta.change(time)
vp_x_loc = time_close + math.round(vp_change * vp_bar_offset)

f_setup_bar(n) =>
    xv1 = ((vp_VmaxId == n) and vp_poc_show) ? math.max(time[vp_lookback], vp_first) : 
         (time_close + math.round(vp_change * (vp_bar_offset - array.get(vp_a_W, n))))
    ys = array.get(vp_a_P, n)
    line.new(x1 = xv1, y1 = ys, x2 = vp_x_loc, y2 = ys, xloc = xloc.bar_time, extend = extend.none, color = (vp_VmaxId == n ? vp_poc_color : vp_bar_color), style  = line.style_solid, width = vp_bar_width)

if barstate.islast
    for iv = 0 to (vp_N_BARS - 1) by 1
        f_setup_bar(iv)

//***********************************************Liquidation Levels using Open Interest Delta

string userSymbol = 'BINANCE' + ":" + string(syminfo.basecurrency) + 'USDT.P'
string Formula = str.format("{0}_OI", userSymbol)
OI = request.security(Formula, timeframe.period, close)
OI_delta = OI - nz(OI[1])

maLength = input(60, title="LQ-MA Length")
numOfLines = 500

OI_delta_MA = ta.sma(OI_delta, maLength)
OI_delta_abs = math.abs(OI_delta)
OI_delta_abs_MA = ta.sma(OI_delta_abs, maLength)

h3 = input.float(3.0, title="Large Liquidation Level")
h2 = input.float(2.0, title="Middle Liquidation Level")
h1 = input.float(1.2, title="Small Liquidation Level")

OI_delta_open_h3 = (OI_delta_abs >= OI_delta_abs_MA * h3) and OI_delta > 0
OI_delta_open_h2 = (OI_delta_abs >= OI_delta_abs_MA * h2 and OI_delta_abs < OI_delta_abs_MA * h3) and OI_delta > 0
OI_delta_open_h1 = (OI_delta_abs >= OI_delta_abs_MA * h1 and OI_delta_abs < OI_delta_abs_MA * h2) and OI_delta > 0

kline_price = (open + close + high + low) / 4

showLine = input.bool(true, title="LQ-Show lines")
showHist = input.bool(true, title="LQ-Show histgram")
showLocalOnly = input.bool(false, title="Only show local liquidation levels")

i_5xColor = input.color(color.rgb(250, 246, 6, 30), '5x Leverage color')
i_10xColor = input.color(color.rgb(253, 217, 9, 30), '10x Leverage color')
i_25xColor = input.color(color.rgb(240, 166, 8, 30), '25x Leverage color')
i_50xColor = input.color(color.rgb(182, 39, 79, 30), '50x Leverage color')
i_100xColor = input.color(color.rgb(182, 3, 53, 30), '100x Leverage color')

var h3Array = array.new_line()
var h2Array = array.new_line()
var h1Array = array.new_line()

// histgram
barColor = input.color(color.rgb(243, 88, 197, 80), "LQ-Bar Color")
numOfBars = input.int(192, 'LQ-Number of bars to lookback')
distLastCandle = input.int(2, 'LQ-Histgram distance from last candle')
local_high = ta.highest(high, numOfBars)
local_low = ta.lowest(low, numOfBars)
rangeHigh = local_high * (1 + local_high / local_low / 10)
rangeLow = local_low * (1 - local_high / local_low / 10)
rangeHeight = rangeHigh - rangeLow

numOfHistograms = input.int(120, 'LQ-Number of histograms (<=120)')
histogramHeight = rangeHeight / numOfHistograms

histogramLowList = array.new_float(numOfHistograms, na)
histogramHighList = array.new_float(numOfHistograms, na)

histogramData = array.new_float()
histogramtargetList = array.new_float(numOfHistograms, 0.0)

var Bars = array.new_box(numOfHistograms, na)
// Clean up drawings every tick
for il =0 to numOfHistograms - 1
    box.delete(array.get(Bars,  il))

f_drawLine(_x1, _x2, _yValue, _lineColor, _style, _width) =>
    line.new(x1=_x1, y1=_yValue, x2=_x2, y2=_yValue, color=_lineColor, style=_style, width=_width)

f_extendArray(_lineArray, _extendLines) =>
    if array.size(_lineArray) > 0
        for _i = array.size(_lineArray) - 1 to 0 by 1

            x2 = line.get_x2(array.get(_lineArray, _i))
            yValue = line.get_y1(array.get(_lineArray, _i))

            if _extendLines or bar_index - 1 == x2 - 1 and not(high > yValue and low < yValue)
                line.set_x2(array.get(_lineArray, _i), bar_index + 1)
                if bar_index == last_bar_index
                    array.push(histogramData, yValue)

f_calculateLeverage100x(_pivotValue, _shortSell) =>
    _shortSell ? _pivotValue * (1 - 0.01) : _pivotValue * (1 + 0.01)

f_calculateLeverage50x( _pivotValue, _shortSell) =>
    _shortSell ? _pivotValue * (1 - 0.02) : _pivotValue * (1 + 0.02)

f_calculateLeverage25x(_pivotValue, _shortSell) =>
    _shortSell ? _pivotValue * (1 - 0.04) : _pivotValue * (1 + 0.04)

f_calculateLeverage10x(_pivotValue, _shortSell) =>
    _shortSell ? _pivotValue * (1 - 0.1) : _pivotValue * (1 + 0.1)

f_calculateLeverage5x(_pivotValue, _shortSell) =>
    _shortSell ? _pivotValue * (1 - 0.2) : _pivotValue * (1 + 0.2)

float yValue = na
int x1 = na
int x2 = na
line ll = na

x1 := bar_index
x2 := bar_index

f_append(Array, ll) =>
    if array.size(Array) == numOfLines
        line.delete(array.shift(Array))
    array.push(Array, ll)

if OI_delta_open_h3
    yValue := f_calculateLeverage5x(kline_price, true)
    ll := f_drawLine(x1, x2, yValue, i_5xColor, line.style_solid, 1)
    f_append(h3Array, ll)

    yValue := f_calculateLeverage5x(kline_price, false)
    ll := f_drawLine(x1, x2, yValue, i_5xColor, line.style_solid, 1)
    f_append(h3Array, ll)

    yValue := f_calculateLeverage10x(kline_price, true)
    ll := f_drawLine(x1, x2, yValue, i_10xColor, line.style_solid, 1)
    f_append(h3Array, ll)

    yValue := f_calculateLeverage10x(kline_price, false)
    ll := f_drawLine(x1, x2, yValue, i_10xColor, line.style_solid, 1)
    f_append(h3Array, ll)

    yValue := f_calculateLeverage25x(kline_price, true)
    ll := f_drawLine(x1, x2, yValue, i_25xColor, line.style_solid, 1)
    f_append(h3Array, ll)

    yValue := f_calculateLeverage25x(kline_price, false)
    ll := f_drawLine(x1, x2, yValue, i_25xColor, line.style_solid, 1)
    f_append(h3Array, ll)

    yValue := f_calculateLeverage50x(kline_price, true)
    ll := f_drawLine(x1, x2, yValue, i_50xColor, line.style_solid, 1)
    f_append(h3Array, ll)

    yValue := f_calculateLeverage50x(kline_price, false)
    ll := f_drawLine(x1, x2, yValue, i_50xColor, line.style_solid, 1)
    f_append(h3Array, ll)

    yValue := f_calculateLeverage100x(kline_price, true)
    ll := f_drawLine(x1, x2, yValue, i_100xColor, line.style_solid, 1)
    f_append(h3Array, ll)

    yValue := f_calculateLeverage100x(kline_price, false)
    ll := f_drawLine(x1, x2, yValue, i_100xColor, line.style_solid, 1)
    f_append(h3Array, ll)

if OI_delta_open_h2
    yValue := f_calculateLeverage10x(kline_price, true)
    ll := f_drawLine(x1, x2, yValue, i_10xColor, line.style_solid, 1)
    f_append(h2Array, ll)

    yValue := f_calculateLeverage10x(kline_price, false)
    ll := f_drawLine(x1, x2, yValue, i_10xColor, line.style_solid, 1)
    f_append(h2Array, ll)

    yValue := f_calculateLeverage25x(kline_price, true)
    ll := f_drawLine(x1, x2, yValue, i_25xColor, line.style_solid, 1)
    f_append(h2Array, ll)

    yValue := f_calculateLeverage25x(kline_price, false)
    ll := f_drawLine(x1, x2, yValue, i_25xColor, line.style_solid, 1)
    f_append(h2Array, ll)

    yValue := f_calculateLeverage50x(kline_price, true)
    ll := f_drawLine(x1, x2, yValue, i_50xColor, line.style_solid, 1)
    f_append(h2Array, ll)

    yValue := f_calculateLeverage50x(kline_price, false)
    ll := f_drawLine(x1, x2, yValue, i_50xColor, line.style_solid, 1)
    f_append(h2Array, ll)

    yValue := f_calculateLeverage100x(kline_price, true)
    ll := f_drawLine(x1, x2, yValue, i_100xColor, line.style_solid, 1)
    f_append(h2Array, ll)

    yValue := f_calculateLeverage100x(kline_price, false)
    ll := f_drawLine(x1, x2, yValue, i_100xColor, line.style_solid, 1)
    f_append(h2Array, ll)

if OI_delta_open_h1
    yValue := f_calculateLeverage25x(kline_price, true)
    ll := f_drawLine(x1, x2, yValue, i_25xColor, line.style_dotted, 1)
    f_append(h1Array, ll)

    yValue := f_calculateLeverage25x(kline_price, false)
    ll := f_drawLine(x1, x2, yValue, i_25xColor, line.style_dotted, 1)
    f_append(h1Array, ll)

    yValue := f_calculateLeverage50x(kline_price, true)
    ll := f_drawLine(x1, x2, yValue, i_50xColor, line.style_dotted, 1)
    f_append(h1Array, ll)

    yValue := f_calculateLeverage50x(kline_price, false)
    ll := f_drawLine(x1, x2, yValue, i_50xColor, line.style_dotted, 1)
    f_append(h1Array, ll)

    yValue := f_calculateLeverage100x(kline_price, true)
    ll := f_drawLine(x1, x2, yValue, i_100xColor, line.style_dotted, 1)
    f_append(h1Array, ll)

    yValue := f_calculateLeverage100x(kline_price, false)
    ll := f_drawLine(x1, x2, yValue, i_100xColor, line.style_dotted, 1)
    f_append(h1Array, ll)

f_extendArray(h3Array, false)
f_extendArray(h2Array, false)
f_extendArray(h1Array, false)

// draw hist
if barstate.islast and showHist
    // Define lows and highs of the histograms
    for il = 0 to numOfHistograms - 1
        histogramLow = rangeLow + histogramHeight * il
        histogramHigh = rangeLow + histogramHeight * (il + 1)
        array.set(histogramLowList, il , histogramLow)
        array.set(histogramHighList, il , histogramHigh)

    for il = 0 to array.size(histogramData) - 1
        yl = array.get(histogramData, il)

        for j = 0 to numOfHistograms - 1
            histogramLow = array.get(histogramLowList, j)
            histogramHigh = array.get(histogramHighList, j)
            if yl >= histogramLow and yl <= histogramHigh
                array.set(histogramtargetList, j, array.get(histogramtargetList, j) + 1)

    for il = 0 to numOfHistograms - 1
        histogramLow = array.get(histogramLowList, il)
        histogramHigh = array.get(histogramHighList, il)
        histogramtarget = array.get(histogramtargetList, il)
        histogramWidth = math.floor((histogramtarget + 0.49) * 2)

        // Draw histograms
        array.set(Bars, il , box.new(left=bar_index + distLastCandle, top=histogramHigh, right=bar_index + distLastCandle + histogramWidth, bottom=histogramLow, bgcolor=barColor, border_color=barColor))

if barstate.islast and not showLine
    for il = 0 to array.size(h3Array) - 1
        line.delete(array.get(h3Array, il))

    for il = 0 to array.size(h2Array) - 1
        line.delete(array.get(h2Array, il))

    for il = 0 to array.size(h1Array) - 1
        line.delete(array.get(h1Array, il))

else if barstate.islast and showLocalOnly
    for il = 0 to array.size(h3Array) - 1
        if line.get_y1(array.get(h3Array, il)) < rangeLow or line.get_y1(array.get(h3Array, il)) > rangeHigh
            line.delete(array.get(h3Array, il))

    for il = 0 to array.size(h2Array) - 1
        if line.get_y1(array.get(h2Array, il)) < rangeLow or line.get_y1(array.get(h2Array, il)) > rangeHigh
            line.delete(array.get(h2Array, il))

    for il = 0 to array.size(h1Array) - 1
        if line.get_y1(array.get(h1Array, il)) < rangeLow or line.get_y1(array.get(h1Array, il)) > rangeHigh
            line.delete(array.get(h1Array, il))



the error gives you the line number in the scipt, check the size from that variable before using array.get()
